# Android BroadcastReceiver vs WakefulBroadcastReceiver vs JobScheduler

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-jobscheduler, wakelock

I am in the process of moving a hybrid Cordova Android app with its own custom plugin from API 19 to 23.  The plugin sets up broadcast receivers for the following

- 'AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating' to execute actions on a ca 30 minute basis
- `LocationServices.fusedLocationAPI` to watch for geolocation changes when the app is backgrounded
- A broadcast receiver to catch push messages captured via [Pushy.me](http://pushy.me).

I find myself slightly lost with the various changes with the different Android APIs.  My understanding is that replacing my current broadcast receivers with `wakeful` versions will work but will only be a stopgap measure since such receivers are deprecated in API 26+.  Just how I can use JobScheduler to watch for geolocation changes and push message broadcasts is far from clear to me. My searches on Google and SO have not yielded anything that I can readily borrow and implement.